# Html/javascript page throws a 404 on iPhone but works fine for PC

Tags: javascript, android, html, iphone, windows-phone

To preface, I am very ignorant in the ways of HTML and javascript so very sorry if I'm making obvious errors.

To elaborate on my title I've uploaded my html page to a domain and was testing on my pc for the correct functionality but cannot access the page to even test on my phone. The page is basically a simple editable spreadsheet which adds each row up and places the sum in the last column.

I have a feeling this will not work for a phone after some brief reading into the subject but I figured I'd ask here in case I'm misunderstanding. What I've read is that tables basically don't work well on phones.

I'm adding the entire page here:

```
code redacted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, I believe, was that the directory I hosted the file in had some mobile coding designed in which encoded url's to use '#' with numbers to access the page. Once I hosted the file in a different more vanilla directory, the file is accessed fine on phones.